# Is it just me or anyone think Ubuntu 14.10 is... "very inconvenient, difficult" to use :|

Tags: gedit, 14.10

In my case, the new Gedit version has no outline border (like a plain white piece of paper) and it bugs my eyes.
The Nautilus file manager, for some unknown reasons? My left click can no longer create a "new txt file" at that location so I end up using Gedit to write the some text first then link it to a location to save instead of the "old way left click".
In some situations, after typing something in Gedit and minimize the program Windows, I cannot click at the Desktop icons anymore. It just like the desktop is frozen!

In general, the update well I don't know much about the differences but the Gedit and Nautilus file manager are disasters in this version (14.10) @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can try XFCE4 desktop (Xubuntu). it's lightweight, uses mousepad, and Thunar file manager which is the best file manage I've used so far. you can install the Xubuntu desktop from software center.

Comment: Yeah, I end up finding alternatives for all of them. Thunar file manager or PCManFM for Nautilus, and Kate editor for Gedit :V

Comment: did any of those worked best for you?

Comment: I really Like Thunar File manager

Comment: good to know. I prefer using gedit but that's just because it was the first text editor I used so it's like a force of habbit.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sublime Text and you will never look back at Gedit again!

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text
```

Comment: Yeah. I just tried the sublime-text 3. It is incredible but requires License. For the Sublime 2, I have not tried it yet but wonder is it free?

Comment: It's free but on occasions it will say something like "This is an unregistered copy" and you can just click OK and continue using it. I't like when you download a free version of WinRAR on Windows.